# How to override swift protocol functions for subclasses (e.g. UILabel from UIView)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, protocols

I'm trying to implement an extended function that should differ based on what type of class is using it.
The objects need to be UIView (or subclass). It should always use function extended on the specified type, but if it doesn't conform to any of them they should use the UIView method instead (as a fallback).

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```swift
protocol aProtocol {
    typealias completionBlock = (_ finished:Bool)->()
    func doSomething(completion: completionBlock)
}


extension UIView: aProtocol {
    func doSomething(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
        print("Im an UIView")
    }
}

extension aProtocol where Self: UILabel {
    func doSomething(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
        print("im an UILabel")
    }
}

extension aProtocol where Self: UIImageView {
    func doSomething(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
        print("im an UIImageView")
    }
}
```

Excecute:

```swift
UIView().doSomething { (foo) in } // Should print "Im an UIView"
UIButton().doSomething { (foo) in } // Should print "Im an UIView" (UIButton doesent have specified extended function so should fall back on the UIView function)
UILabel().doSomething { (foo) in } // Should print "im an UILabel"
UIImageView().doSomething { (foo) in } // Should print "im an UIImageView"
```

Which now prints:

```
Im an UIView
Im an UIView
Im an UIView
Im an UIView
```

This means that it always uses the UIView method, even though I want it to use it's own methods. My goal is so it prints:

```
Im an UIView
Im an UIView
im an UILabel
im an UIImageView
```

Comment: It's because a UILabel is always a UIView,

Comment: @vollan sure, UILabel will always be a subclass of UIView. What I'm trying to figure out is if the specified functions for the subclasses can override the UIView function.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. posted answer below.

Comment: @Pointblaster checkout my answer. I explained why is this happening and how you can achieve your needs.

Comment: The problem is that the extensions don't create an override. They define a new method.

Comment: Actually if there's a problem here it's that the compiler doesn't warn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that as below, You just need to expose `aProtocol` to `Objective-c` runtime for `overriding` its methods in the `extension`.

```
@objc protocol aProtocol {
    typealias completionBlock = (_ finished:Bool)->()
    func doSomething(completion: completionBlock)
}

extension UIView: aProtocol {
    func doSomething(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
        print("Im an UIView")
    }
}

extension UILabel {
    override func doSomething(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
        // you can call super.doSomething(completion: completion)
        print("im an UILabel")
    }
}

extension UIImageView {
    override func doSomething(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
        // you can call super.doSomething(completion: completion)
        print("im an UIImageView")
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Im an UIView
Im an UIView
im an UILabel
im an UIImageView
```

Comment: That sure is both interesting and wierd. Can you explain why it would work with an @objc protocol?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### - The answer

concrete type conforming to a protocol will used over the protocol constraint. So by changing this:

```
extension UIView: aProtocol {
    func doSomething(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
        print("Im an UIView")
    }
}
```

to this:

```
extension aProtocol where Self: UIView {
    func doSomething(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
        print("im an UIView")
    }
}

extension UIView: aProtocol {}
```

Your code will work as you expect.

### - The alternative

You can achieve all of your desired prints with this:

```
extension aProtocol {
    func doSomething(completion: completionBlock) {
        print("im a \(type(of: self))")
    }
}

extension UIView: aProtocol {}
```

This means you can check the actual type of the object right inside the protocol extension.

### - The explanation

Protocol extensions doesn't override any method. In fact, they are just default implementation if the actual concrete type doesn't implement it.

And **protocol constraint** defines witch type can infer it's default implementation. So:

```
extension aProtocol where Self: UILabel
```

means any subcalss of `UILabel` that is conformed to `aProtocol` and does not implement the requirements should infer de default implementation. So this will work only if `UILabel` conforms to `aProtocol` directly:

```
extension UILabel: aProtocol {}
```

or if it's supercalss conforms to it:

```
extension UIView: aProtocol {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol aProtocol {
    typealias completionBlock = (_ finished:Bool)->()
}

extension aProtocol {

    func doSomething(completion: completionBlock) {
        switch self {
        case is UILabel:
            print("im a label")
            break
        case is UIView:
            print("im a view")
            break
        default:
            break
        }

    }
}

extension UIView: aProtocol{}
extension UILabel: aProtocol{}

func testing() {

    let view = UIView()
    view.doSomething { (value) in
        // Do something
    }

    let label = UILabel()
    label.doSomething { (value) in
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Make sure that the case of UIView is in the bottom of the list (or at least below everything you want to block out)